# How to get object id in facebook when i call GraphAPI.get_object()

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, pyfacebook

my goal is to call facebook api and get some data from insight

```
graph = GraphAPI(access_token=access_token, version="v19.0")

# Define the parameters for the request
params = {
    'date_preset': 'last_7d'
}


# Make the request to retrieve insights for the ad campaign
insights = graph.get_object(
    id="123/insights",
    params=params,
    object_id =''  <--- what should be this?

)
```

when i run

```
insights = graph.get_object(
    id="120206013967120683/insights",
    params=params)
```

It show `TypeError: GraphAPI.get_object() missing 1 required positional argument: 'object_id'`, but i didn't know where can i retrieve the object_id from facebook ads manager or meta for developer

Guide to retrieve`object_id`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.